# Splitting an array into columns, where the total child elements is roughly equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to achieve some tricky functionality within Javascript for creating a directory page. The directory page works by having items assigned to a letter (which is the first letter of the item).

For example:

```
{ 
    A: [Alfie, Amelia, Ava, Alex, Aaron],
    B: [Ben, Bella, Blake, Bailey, Bradley]
    ... 
}
```

Essentially, the output should be 4 sub-arrays. These sub-arrays should be an array of letters. However, the functionality should decide how many letters are in each array by the number of items that are assigned to that letter.

So, the first array could contain only 3 letters, as each letter has 5 items assigned (totalling). The second array could contain 7 letters, as the total of sum of their children is roughly 15.

For example:

```
[ 
    [A (5), B (5), C (5)],
    [E (4), F (1), G (1), H (2), I (3), J (2), K (1)]
    ... 
]
```

It's worth nothing that it **isn't important** for each of the 4 arrays to contain **EXACTLY** the same amount of items because it's likely for this not to be possible.

I'm not sure how I'd begin to achieve this functionality. Any points in the right direction would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you know the number of groups that you want as a result?

Comment: `the output should be 4 sub-arrays` is 4 fixed? Or depends on something?

Comment: The 4 is not fixed, with a solution I'd work it to result into either 3 of 4 sub-arrays. The reason for 4, is there are 4 columns to output the data into. The 3 sub-arrays would be used for smaller screen sizes.

Comment: This may give you a better understanding of what & why I'm trying to achieve this solution: https://i.imgur.com/yGtBSKT.png

Comment: If you're just trying to fill a table like in your picture, why are you not willing to break up the same letter into two columns? It would allow you to get perfect balance

Comment: So if the desired limit is 15, and you are unlucky and have a letter with 50 items, what will you do? What if you want 4 columns, but it happens there are only 2 distinct letters?

Comment: @Berthur It's purely a design decision. The directory would look odd with two of the same letter, would you not agree?

Comment: @trincot the desired limit is not 15, this was an example. The limit is 4 (roughly) equal columns.

Comment: Yes, but that's not my point. If the (calculated) limit is 50 (or whatever) and you have group that has 3 times more entries (because it has 75% of all entries), what will you do? What if there are only two groups? What will you do?

Comment: @trincot This is a very edge case. The data within this will very rarely (if ever) be something like this. If something like this was to occur, the error would lie within the data source rather than the front-end code.

Comment: In the image you provided the titles also take space, even more than the items, so are you sure you only want to count the strings in the arrays only?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach for the question asked.

First, it is easy given maximum height of any column to figure out how many columns you will need.  Just attempt it.

Next, the maximum height must be in the range from the largest number of items assigned to a letter, to the sum of all items assigned to all letters.

And now we can do a binary search to find the smallest allowed height that has at most 4 columns.  The key loop should look something like:

```
while (lower < upper) {
    let mid = Math.ceil((lower + upper)/2);
    if (divideIntoColumns(items, mid).length <= 4) {
        lower = mid;
    }
    else {
         upper = mid - 1;
    }
}
```

As @trincot pointed out, titles also take space. The easiest way to take that into account is do make you `divideIntoColumns` function be the estimated height of the column in a convenient unit (eg pixels).  Even if that multiplies the size of your numbers by a factor of 20, that's just 4-5 extra rounds of binary search, which will be fine.